# How to set control's Width or Height property using a ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I set a control's width or height using `ControlTemplate`?

For instance, I have this template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GridSplitterTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
    <!-- What goes here? -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

This is the template usage:

```
<GridSplitter Template="{StaticResource GridSplitterTemplate}"
              Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

And I also have several `GridSplitter`s, all of which should have `GridSplitter.Width="10"`. How can I set it once using a `ControlTemplate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to "hard code" the width/height using the ControlTemplate, then just set the root element's width/height:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GridSplitterTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
    <!-- What goes here? -->
    <Grid Width="10" Height="10">
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

---

I think @lll has a point though -- this is typically something you would do with a Style.  What happens if you want an instance of your GridSplitter with a different size?  And you don't lose anything by using this approach:

```
<Style x:Key="GridSplitterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridSplitterTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
                <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                </Grid>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now, just have your instances reference the style instead of the control template:

```
<GridSplitter Style="{StaticResource GridSplitterStyle}"
```

This allows you to still have a default height/width of 10, but instances can override that if they need to:

```
<GridSplitter Style="{StaticResource GridSplitterStyle}" Width=20
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning is if you don't want your control template nested in a style for organizational purposes, you can reference the template inside the style's setter like this: `<Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource GridSplitterTemplate}"/>`

Answer (score 2):

You just want to set the `Style` not the `ControlTemplate`

```
<Style TargetType="GridSplitter" x:Name="GridSplitterTemplate">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>/
</Style>
```

If you really want to use `ControlTemplate`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GridSplitterTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
            <GridSplitter Width="10"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I can't take advantage of the `ControlTemplate` that I use anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I updated my question - I use this template on an existing `GridSplitter`, so I don't want to host another one inside the `GridSplitter`'s template

Comment: Sorry, you don't understand how `ControlTemplate` works. That will not host another `GridSplitter` within a `GridSplitter`. That overrwrites your `Template` so technically, you are customizing its look and will create one `GridSplitter` and nothing else. And if you really want to set the width just once to `10` then I really suggest you look into using `Styles`

Comment: Well, it doesn't work... and in general, that's not true - I host several controls inside the `ControlTemplate` to display composite control and it's working great - my `GridSplitter` hosts a `Grid` that contains whole bunch of other controls.

Comment: And I don't want to use `Style` since I already have the template, so why use extra code?

Comment: I think you've mistaken with what I said. Since you don't want to use `styles` and you want less code well let me tell you that, that won't and because you want to keep reusing `ControlTemplate` without repeating setting the `Width` to `10` then you would then have to explicitly rehost it with `GridSplitter`. I don't understand why you don't want to use `Styles`. And it does work in my machine both implementation. I tested it.